# how can i use _getch() without using "using namespace std;?

Tags: c++

for using **iostream** library we have to write **using std::cin;** or something like that.

what should I write for using **_getch()**?

**I don't want to use "using namespace std;**

Comment: `getch` is neither in the namespace std nor anywhere else. Don´t use it, it´s non-standard stone-age stuff.

Comment: And no, you don´t *have* to write `using std::cin`.. Read more about namespaces and the possibilites to use them.

Comment: You don't need to write "using".  You can just write std::cin.  Actually in my opinion it's better to prefix with namespace rather than using `using', at least because it allows you to know which version of something you're actually calling (in cases where there may be more than one).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a function by the name of `_getch()` in standard c++. There *are* multiple ways of getting a character from a stream, though. If you want to operate on the stream like with

```
using namespace std;

...

cin >> myvariable;
```

But by retrieving a single character instead, what you want is the member function of input streams known as `get()`

You can call it on the console input stream with `cin.get()`, which will return a character read from the console. If you want to do without the `using namespace std;` line, you simply use `std::cin.get()` instead.

This is because almost everything in the standard libraries is located in the `std` namespace. You can always access something in a namespace by prefixing it with the namespace name, rather than using a using-statement: with the first code, an equivalent would be

```
std::cin >> myvariable
```

there are some other neat things you can do with namespaces and using statements, such as specifying that you only want to use a single item in the namespace without the specifier. This can be done with the line (keeping with playing around with `cin`):

```
using std::cin;
```

which lets you say

```
cin >> myvariable;
```

Comment: ... or remove the first line and write std::cin >> myvariable :p.

Comment: @Robinson I wanted to show how they're apparently familiar with getting input. Since they specified the absence of the using-statement, I figured they wanted to get rid of it. But yeah, I'll edit it.

Comment: Yes, see my comment above.  Just personal preference but I always use the prefix rather than `using'.

Comment: @Robinson Eh, I do too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `#include <conio.h>`

Answer (score 0):

[`_getch()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) is a (non-standard, Microsoft specific) **C function**: since there is no concept of "namespace" in C, you can't use `"using namespace std;"` for `_getch`.

Comment: `_getch() is a C function:` Is it? I don´t think so. Especially because everything with an underline first is compiler-dependent.

Comment: @deviantfan: It's not standard C, but it's part of the Microsoft CRT. I also inserted a link to proper MSDN page.

Comment: It's in the Microsoft C libraries but isn't in "the standard".

Answer (score -1):

Consider a situation, when we have two persons with the same name,Emma, in the same class. Whenever we need to differentiate them definitely we would have to use some additional information along with their name, like either the area if they live in different area or their mother or father name, etc.

using namespace std; is nothing but the pool of values that is used to differentiate the meaning of the user defined variables and in-built key words.

So using _ `

```
std:: getch();
```

` //will work perfectly fine and it will not require any library